# METEOR - integrating a prebuilt HTML/CSS/JS Theme with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know if there is some kind of tutorial or guide how I can integrate an already designed theme with meteor core structure. For example I have this template here: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/ that I integrated into this: http://sailsadria.meteor.com/
I managed to setup the CSS and HTML but the JS is killing me. You can see this includes that he needs:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/creative.js"></script>
```

I have added bootstrap and Jquery via packages but don't know if that does the trick?

And yeah this guy has some cool solutions: https://www.yauh.de/using-pre-made-themes-with-meteor/ but I really didn't understand the part where he explains how to integrate the custom JS files

How can I include all those files into the meteor structure? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already been told repeatedly why using themes is a bad idea....

Proper way: turn them all into packages.

Quick and dirty: Copy all the js files, drop them into `client/compatibility`, rename them so predecessors are alphanumerically before successors.

Comment: Sorry, but you are the first telling me this :D, could you clarify a bit more on that topic as I'm scraping the web for the last 2 days and didn't find much info on this. Anyway the reason why I'm doing this is because I need a nice and slick "presentation website" like this one and I need meteor for handling "form submit" messages...As I'm not a great designer type... fuk it this is the quickest solution. Have you got any reference or good guid while you are here for turning it into packages?

Comment: using meteor just for handling form submits is like driving an airplane on the highway during rush hour... If you don't need DDP, websockets, minimongo, etc. you'd be better off using node + express, hosting costs will be less, page loads will be faster, etc. You can learn about making packages on atmosphere, but seriously, meteor isn't the tool for *this* job.

Comment: I started developing on meteor just a month ago and I love it, and I don't know any other "backend" like php or ror to go into now, and I need this quick... Is node + express gonna take me a lot of resources (time) to get the grip?

Comment: @MattK Yeah, but why go out and buy/learn to drive a car when I have a perfectly good airplane in the back shed? ;)

Comment: node is what meteor is built on, minus the oplog, pub sub, websockets, etc. @LukeP, the answer to your question is fuel efficiency. When you spend 10 hours troubleshooting a websocket problem in production when your app doesn't even use them, or when you have to serve up an extra megabyte of JS that your app won't ever use. Right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Matt K is right about his comment staging an airplane on an highway during rush hour (lol). I don't know how much time you have but if you really want to use meteor and deliver on short notice, you can try [meteor kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com/getting_started).

Before you jump on it (because it could mean a great deal of time saved) be warned that if you choose it you will end up with a satisfying website easily generated, but you will be on your own if you want to implement all the extra stuff you could need. So it depends on how much custom stuff you want.

This being said, I think it will provide a clean boilerplate, including most of the basic features you could expect (user/admin identification, iron-router navigation, all the website structure generated, etc.) and it will allow you to choose one of the themes from bootswatch and get it set up automatically.

However, if you want to change for another theme, I am not sure how you should proceed. You could probably just drop the theme files in the `client\styles\theme` folder, I never tried.

Comment: Thanx man! Don't worry, this is basically a onepager presentation website with a big header photo, few details and a form to book a sailing trip (if we are going specific). I will definitely look into kitchen ;)