# Integrate UI framework with Meteor 1.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, cdn

I'd like to integrate the [AdminLTE Bootstrap template](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) into a Meteor 1.4 app.

[Meteor recommends using a CDN](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#cdn). Do CDNs only work with files placed in `/public` or  `/client/compatibility`  folder?

In other words, if one wanted to properly integrate a theme into Meteor, where should they place the CSS/JS files?

*Note: this was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571230/meteor-integrating-a-prebuilt-html-css-js-theme-with-meteor) a year ago for a older version of Meteor. It would be great to know the answer for the current version of Meteor (1.4). Thanks*